# how to save opengl output window into file[ply or pcd]

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, point-clouds, triangulation

now I am studying about triangulation then I found this code from GITHUB,

https://github.com/PranjalSahu/Point-Cloud-Triangulation/blob/master/bun10.cpp

this works fine,
I post some code here

```
void renderScene(void){
int temporig, tempdest;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();   

glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);    
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for(int u=0; u<40000;u = u+5){          
        glVertex3f(xcoor[u], ycoor[u], zcoor[u]);
    }
glEnd();     

glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);   
glBegin(GL_LINES);

for(int i=0;i<tcount;++i){
    int ti = xcolist[i];
    int tj = ycolist[i];
    float dist = 0;
    dist = sqrt((xcoor[ti]-xcoor[tj])*(xcoor[ti]-xcoor[tj])+(ycoor[ti]-ycoor[tj])*(ycoor[ti]-ycoor[tj])+(zcoor[ti]-zcoor[tj])*(zcoor[ti]-zcoor[tj]));
    if(dist < 0.25){
        glVertex3f(xcoor[ti], ycoor[ti], zcoor[ti]);
        glVertex3f(xcoor[tj], ycoor[tj], zcoor[tj]);
    }
 }  
    glEnd();

 glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

...........
...........
...........

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
glutCreateWindow("");
init();
glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
glutIdleFunc(renderScene);
glutKeyboardFunc(inputKey);
glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

my input is point cloud(.ply file ) and my output was showed by output window.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcwCa.png) 
this is the output window

now I want to save my output window data into file(ply or pcd)
I spend a huge time for googling but I never notice reliable resource about this

known person come front and help me with proper code.

Comment: A [`Polygon File (PLY)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) is just a text file. Open a new text file and write the formatted text to the file. How to assemble the formatted text depends on your data. See [PLY file read and write](https://imkaywu.github.io/blog/2016/04/ply/).

Comment: thankyou for your reply, I aim to save OpenGL output window data as ply or pcd . using glut/OpenGL graphics set my point cloud triangulated, now if try to save vertices again its looks like just point cloud, I want to save the triangulated mesh[connected pointcloud].,PLY file read and write help to my requirement?

Comment: Read about the [PLY - Polygon File Format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/). The file consist of coordinates and faces (indices). If the you've triangulated data, then you're faces consist of 3 vertices. But you have to read the format specification your self. It makes no sens to copy the format to an answer.